# What is the difference between "above" and "over"?

Tags: prepositions

We ordinarily apply *above* and *over* in place of each other.

Is there an accurate difference between them? If so, what is it?
When do we use *above* and when do we use *over*?  what is the similarities between them?

we want to know what are differences exactly and accurately among them? I need a response which accurately draw these differences?

Comment: @Andrew Leach:I think that this response is not complete and doesn't explain the differences and similarities as well as possible..

Comment: Please explain in this question exactly what it is you don't find in the other one. The answer on the other question contains a sentence which seems to answer both aspects: *In many, many cases they're equivalent (although "over" is more common.) When they differ, it's because "above" is typically used only for location, while "over" can be used for movement from one place to another.*

Comment: @ Andrew Leach: though it is referred by the response as you mention it, but this response is not accurate. I need a clear answer...

Comment: Well, in that case, that question is the place for a better answer. This question will point to that one. Or: state explicitly what you do not understand. Just "what are the differences" ***is*** covered there.